# Using FBO particles with a first person camera in Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am attempting to make a first person experiment incorporating FBO particles (similar to Mr. Doob's [sporel](http://christmasexperiments.com/2013/24/).

I create the position of my particles in a data texture, and then in my vertex shader I do a lookup on the texture to get the position of that particle.

```
  uniform sampler2D map;
  varying vec2 vUv;
  varying vec3 vPosition;
  void main(void) {
  vec2 uv = position.xy;
  vec4 data = texture2D(map, uv);

  vPosition = data.xyz;
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
```

This is working great, and initially I see a field of particles as shown here...
[image: particles]

The problem is when I walk a bit and rotate, all of the particles suddenly disappear. I did a bunch of searching around for a solution, and found [this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3863) which suggested setting material.depthWrite to false. I did this, to no avail- here is my ShaderMaterial definition:

```
 var particleMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
uniforms: uniforms,
vertexShader: shaders.vertexShaders.floor,
fragmentShader: shaders.fragmentShaders.floor,
blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
depthWrite: false,
```

})

I am at a loss right now and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! Eric

Comment: I've been walking and walking, even did some strafing, no way that i can get the particles to appear. Here's an idea though, if the system is so spread out, it could be getting eliminated from rendering before ever making it to the shader above. Now this is a guess, but it could happen if you don't have your bounding boxes set correctly, which can totally be the case if you are just dynamically creating these. (the bounds should probably be the size of your room). At one point, three.js may think all the perticles are confined to a volume thats not in your view... Awesome noise on the ceiling!

Comment: That's a really good point! I moved on to another part of the project but will try that again soon! Thanks!